# How do I disable the shadow only on one edge?

Tags: html, css

How do I get rid of the shadow in the red area below? I have seen other similar questions but don't know how to apply that here.

[image: Rid it]

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xFa9M/

CSS:-

```
#list li{
border: 2px solid black;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
padding: 4em;
z-index: 1;
}

#list li .tip{
position: absolute;
left: 200px;
top: 0px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-left-width: 0px;
z-index: 0;
display: none;
}

#list li:hover{
-moz-box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px black;
-webkit-box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px black;
box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #555;
}

#list li:hover .tip{
-moz-box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px black;
-webkit-box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px black;
box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #555;
 }
```

Html:-

```
<ul id="list">
        <li class="top">About Me
            <div class="tip">Asas</div>
        <li>Garage
        <li class="bottom">My Blog
</ul>
```

Please note that it is ok for me to use JS code tricks, if needed.

Comment: Please provide HTML and CSS code. How did you apply it?

Comment: It's bad practice to not close your tags. Make sure you include your `</li>` tag for each list element.

Comment: I read somewhere that for `<li>` it is optional. Even Google practices this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are having problems with the middle li's having shadow, while you only want the first (and maybe last) li to have shadow.

If I understood correctly, you could use the li:first-child and li:last-child to set the shadow to the first and last element of your list.

But this is not the case. If you want to hide the left shadow on your .tip, you should set the first paramater of box-shadow to 0px. The first parameter is the horizontal offset.

Like here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rf47W/

Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes somewhat. The bottom edge shadow also needs to merge together to give the feeling of being one object.

Comment: Thanks Anze. By far this is the best compromise.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Remember that if you want the shadows to work on older IE you should also add the MS DXImageTransform. Read more here: http://placenamehere.com/article/384/css3boxshadowininternetexplorerblurshadow/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

In order to get around the issue, don't assign dropshadows to the "about me" and "asas" boxes separately, but rather wrap them in a single container and apply the shadow to it.

Comment: This could be a problem for me. The "asas" box can have more height than the "about me" box. So the container will grow in size to cover the others below the "about me" box.

Comment: In that case, it seems impossible. One other trick I can think of is setting the menu elements' z-index to 1, and "asas" to 0. No warranties, and it's hacky, but you still might want to try this.

Comment: Yes tried that. It seems to have effect only if `.tip`'s `z-index` is -1. Anyway in this case the bottom edge shadow's continuity breaks. So, it is not useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried targeting that element with a specific class/id/whatever selector and inserting 
the code below?

```
-moz-box-shadow:none;  
-webkit-box-shadow: none;  
box-shadow: none;
```

Comment: If I do that then the "asas" box won't have any shadow. I need the shadow under that box.

Comment: can you post the full thing on something like http://jsfiddle.net so we can get a better understanding ? I, for one, get a totally a different result than your image ( in latest Chrome and latest FF - http://jsfiddle.net/toxik/qnT4v/ ) and don't fully understand what you want to achieve

Comment: I have been playing around so the code is quite dirty. Anyway here it goes: http://jsfiddle.net/Ub59z/

Answer (score 0):

The CSS and HTML given does not produce the display shown in the image, so I'm having to guess, but try wrapping the asas box in another box with bottom padding and hidden overflow.